# How to complete URL's with only domain name

Tags: python, url

So i am calling out urls i.e. "domain.xyz" from a .csv file. The purpose is to use the requests module to GET/HEAD responses. Using this code as a work around to add a string.

```
     x = "http://www."+str('domain.com')
     response = requests.head(x)
```

The problem here is not all "domain.com" entries in my .csv start with standard **http://www.**. What's the best way to complete the URL before using the requests module?

p.s. I am looking for something similar to what Chromes address bar does to complete a url. For instance when we enter 'abc.com'. it completes it to "http://www.abc.xyz".

Comment: There is no way. If the domain is domain.com that is what you need to send the request to. There is no way to know if www.domain.com exists / is correct other than trying to call it and reacting to an exception if raised. Even inferring the protocol http / https is not doable, some sites only support one and not the other.

Comment: You can look at each of your domains and if it doesn't [start with](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) `www.`, you can append that. But some domains may not support a `www...` subdomain. So you could try to hit the domain that you have in your data, and if that fails, fall back to trying it with the added `www.` if it doesn't have that yet.

Comment: @luk2302 So I went back and tried google.com without http://www. with requests module. this is what i got  ""Invalid URL 'google.com': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://google.com?"". This tells me Requests can't GET/HEAD without https://. So I appended that to all if the domains. This is the exception I'm getting since ""An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"". Any ideas on what's happening?

Comment: Yes, you need a Schema but you cannot know whether http or https is correct, you could always try https but that is simply not guaranteed to work. Same exact thing with prepending www. Some only support one, some only support the other, some support both and some may only support `ftp://ww2.domain.com` - you can only guess and try to build valid urls but none of them are guaranteed to work.

Comment: Thanks for the help. So I fiddled around a bit more and finally got around the exceptions. I check for exceptions with try: except: blocks. If a exception is raised with http: i swap it out with https:/ and some other generic schema from the list. Isn't working for all the domains I have like you already said. But it's getting the job done for most. So once again loads of thanks.